# Sitting under a tree in a valid Sukkah

Tags: sukkot, sukkah, trees, invalid-pasul

If someone built a Sukkah large enough to enclose a tree, but not more than 20 Amoth tall, may someone sit under that tree on Sukkoth?

Comment: How is this different from [sitting under a bed](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%91_%D7%90)?

Comment: That's probably the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the distance from the ground to the bottom of the tree is ten tefachim, you don't fulfill your obligation ([Orach Chayim 627:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=171)).

Answer (score 1):

No, because the sukkah is supposed to be the one that covers you, not the tree.

Comment: Can you add a source?